# Is the Weierstrass $\wp$-function compatible with automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, elliptic-functions

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\tag{$*$}
\sigma(\wp(z; \Lambda))=\wp(\sigma(z); \sigma(\Lambda))?
\end{equation}
Of course, this is obvious if $\sigma$ is continuous, but most automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ are not continuous.

However, I still suspect this to be true for the following reason: If $E/\mathbb{C}$ is an elliptic curve such that $E(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ and $[\,\cdot\,]_E$ denotes the normalised isomorphism from $\mathcal{O}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathrm{End}(E)$, then $\sigma([\alpha]_E)=[\sigma(\alpha)]_{\sigma(E)}$ for any $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}$ (see Silverman, for example). Chasing this around a few diagrams then seems to imply $(*)$.

So I guess I am really asking two things here: First, is $(*)$ indeed true and second, if so, can we see this directly, i.e. without the detour using elliptic curves?

Comment: What sort of "automorphisms" are you talking about?  Field automorphisms?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, although I would already be content with $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ for some finite extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't know what (*) means if $\sigma$ is an automorphism of a finite extension: $\wp$ will almost certainly not map that finite extension to itself, so the left side of the equation is undefined.

Comment: What I had in mind was to extend $\sigma\in\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ to some automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. Then again, I now realise that this does not put any restrictions on $\sigma$ since you can just take any $\sigma\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ and restrict it to $L$ to get an element of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ (at least if $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed Galois).

Comment: I also don't follow your proposed argument.  I'm not sure what you mean by $\mathcal{O}$ but in any case, I don't see how you could get from $\sigma([\alpha]_E)=[\sigma(\alpha)]_{\sigma(E)}$ for $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}$ to $(*)$ holding for *all* $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I was thinking about the case with complex multiplication so $\mathcal{O}$ was supposed to be an order in an imaginary quadratic number field; however, it was irrelevant to the question if that is the case or if $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{Z}$ instead. In any case, I realised that my argument was misguided, see below, thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  For instance, take $\Lambda$ to be generated by $1$ and $i$, so $\sigma(\Lambda)$ is always equal to $\Lambda$.  Then you are asking whether the $\wp$-function satisfies $\sigma(\wp(z))=\wp(\sigma(z))$.  Now take any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z$ and $\wp(z)$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.  (Such a $z$ exists by the Baire category theorem, for instance: for any nonzero $p\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, the set of $z$ such that $p(z,\wp(z))=0$ is closed and has empty interior, and there are only countably many such $p$.)  An automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ can then send $z$ and $\wp(z)$ to any other pair $a,b$ of algebraically independent elements of $\mathbb{C}$.  In particular, you can choose such a pair for which $b\neq \wp(a)$, so $\sigma(\wp(z))\neq\wp(\sigma(z))$.

Comment: Thank you! I also just realised that the argument using diagrams was wrong, but it is still nice to have a counterexample.